# Can you replace char based on which method calls toString()

Tags: java, string, replace

I am quite confused because I have been given the task to display a `List<E>` with the format [E1,E2,E3] and a `SortedSet<E>` with the format {E1, E2, E3}, I have Overriden the toString method for my type of objects, but I do not know how to replace the squared braces with curly ones when the return type of the method I call `toString()` on is of type `SortedSet<E>`, I know that I can use `toString.replace()`, problem is I cannot use it on my unit tests, I'm only allowed to call `toString()` in those, any idea is greatly appreciated.

Edit, here's the code(I left it out intentionally before because it was in Italian on some points and I didn't want to confuse people more):

```
public List<Attrezzo> getContenutoOrdinatoPerPeso(){
        List<Attrezzo> out=new ArrayList<Attrezzo>();
        out.addAll(this.attrezzi.values());
        out.sort(new ComparatorePrimaPesoPoiNome());
        return out;

    }
    public SortedSet<Attrezzo> getContenutoOrdinatoPerNome(){
        SortedSet<Attrezzo> outAttrezzos= new TreeSet<Attrezzo>(new ComparatorePerNome());
        outAttrezzos.addAll(this.attrezzi.values());
        return outAttrezzos;
    }
```

This is what an example of a unit test would look like

```
@Test
public void testGetContenutoOrdinatoPerNome(){
assertEquals("{E1, E2, E3}",this.borsa.getContenutoOrdinatoPerNome().toString);
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Are you implementing your own List or SortedSet?  If not, then you don't control their toString implementations, so you'll have to use replace or some other means of manually switching the braces.

Comment: I am using java.util's, my thought was to declare an inner class that would do that type of formatting and return it, but I don't know how to then later print that in the unit tests, since both methods have to return a List and a SortedSet, I also cannot use System.out.println() to directly print the List or SortedSet

Comment: Displaying a List as a String than is different to its `toString()` does **not** mean you must override `toString()` (although you could use aspect, but that would replace the impl for all instances and is the wrong solution anyway). You should write a method that accepts a List and returns the List rendered as a String.

Comment: I thought of that too, but my professor specified that both methods should return that format when called, which doesn't really make sense since that would make them not of type ```List<E>``` or ```SortedSet<E>```that's why I thought he might be asking for when ```toString()``` is used on the return type of those methods.

Comment: If there is a requirement to use `toString()`, make each object with an anonymous inner class overriding `toString()`

Comment: I see your concern but doesn't the object have a `toString()` based on what kind of object it actually is, not the type your method returns?

Comment: @clwhisk the object has its own ```toString()``` method, the only problem is when calling ```toString()``` on the ```List<E>``` and printing that to console it uses the original formatting for the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you've tried anonymous inner classes but I'll put this proof of concept here for reference.

```
List<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<Integer>(){
    public String toString(){
        return "{}";
    }
};
System.out.println(obj);//{}
```

Comment: So after some work on this, it would seem it's exactly what I wanted, idk what I was doing before with inner classes that wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is instanceof.  something like:

```
String makeString(Collection myCollection)
{
    String stringedCollection = makeCommaSeparatedString(myCollection);
    if(myCollection instanceof List)
    {
        // surround it with square brackets
        return "["+stringedCollection+"]";
    }
    else if(myColleciton instanceof Set)
    {
        // surround with braces
        return "{"+stringedCollection+"}";
    }
```

This isn't actually based on what was calling your function, but what was passed in.

Comment: I cannot use instanceOf in this case because the type of object inside the collections is the same, so it doesn't make sense, the only solution I can think of would be to create a method then pass the return of both methods above as a parameter and return a string, but it seems very inconvenient.  Edit, I hadn't refreshed my page, I couldn't see your solution, so yeah what I was thinking, still a reach around for no apparent reason.

Comment: Why would instanceof be inappropriate?  It's perfectly fine that "the type of object inside the collections is the same," and it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Klaudio you aren't checking the type of the object inside the collection, you are checking the type of the collection itself.  If you were checking the type of the object inside the collection it would have to bee inside a loop and would not solve the problem you were asking.